# In the proof of corollary associated to the closed subgroup theorem

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups

I'am reading the John M. Lee, Introduction to Smooth manifolds and I have a question.

Let $G$ be a Lie group with Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$. And let $\operatorname{exp} : \mathfrak{g} \to G$ be the exponential map.

[image]

Here, the preceding proposition and formula (20.4) is :

[image]

And the proposition 20.8 (d) is : For any $X \in \mathfrak{g}$ and $n\in \mathbb{Z}$, $(\operatorname{exp}X)^n=\operatorname{exp}(nX)$.

Now, why the underlined statement is true? The limit is with respect to the topology associated to the lie group structure on $G$? If so, how to show the above formula (20.5) more rigorously ?

Comment: Well, $\exp$ is continuous, and its input converges to $t(X+Y)$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Yes. Thank you. And.. $\mathfrak{g}$ is equipped with any norm topology.
    
     It is not certainly sure that $t(X+Y) + (t^2/n)\operatorname{Z}(t/n)$ converges to $t(X+Y)$ in norm topology ; i.e., $||(t^2/n)\operatorname{Z}(t/n)||=|t^2/n| ||\operatorname{Z}(t/n)||$ goes to zero as $n\to \infty$? ($\operatorname{Z}(t/n)$ also depends on $n$)